# How do I uninstall Android Studio if it was installed via Ubuntu Developer Tools Center (UDTC)?

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, android, software-uninstall, android-studio

I installed Android Studio Beta on Xubuntu 14.10 by executing `udtc android` in a terminal. **I want to uninstall it such that there are no traces on my machine of its prior existence.**

I chose `~/tools/android/android-studio/` as my installation path. If I installed Android Studio Beta by extracting the archive provided by Google, I'm confident that deleting only the `tools` directory would satisfy my requirement. But the `udtc` command also created the file `~/.local/share/applications/android-studio.desktop`. I suspect that there are more such files outside of my installation path.

What must I do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: What is `utdc`? Never heard that and can't find it on the internet...

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to write Ubuntu Developer Tool Center (UDTC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall android studio by issuing

```
udtc --remove android
```

from your console. Be aware that it won't ask you for confirmation

Comment: The version of udtc that I used when I asked my question was 0.0.5. This answer works for versions 0.1.* and up.